# C# - Pan cursor

Tags: c#, cursor

I'm implementing panning of a large image in a PictureBox control, and I have no problem setting the appropriate directional pan cursors. However, I can't seem to find the image used for the origin of the pan (a circle with arrows inside of it).

Where can I find it?

Comment: Not sure what your are talking about.  Guessing: it's not an image, it's a cursor.  Cursors.SizeAll.  Doesn't have anything to do with an "origin" though.

Comment: When you first middle-click down to start panning, there's an icon or cursor that stays where you clicked down, while you move the mouse around to pan. The panning direction is relative to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the *image* that you are looking is not included in the framework. Every app uses their own cursor for that (AFAIK). The closest you can get is using Cursors.SizeAll as Hans Passant already told you:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
```

Comment: Thanks Matías, I think you are right.
It seems strange to me that the image is not included, or at least mentioned in the documentation, though.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation about the scroll cursor origin. Putting a window in "reader mode" by calling DoReaderMode() will plant the scroll origin icon and scroll the window.

Doc page mentioning the scroll origin icon (near the bottom of the page):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545459.aspx

Doc page for DoReaderMode():

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775599(VS.85).aspx