# .Net Scrollable Control, Center button pan

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Is there a way to enable a default pan behavior in the .Net scrollable control when you press down on the center scroll button, or Is that a behavior you have to implement yourself?

You know like in some programs where you press down on the center button and it give you an arrow cursor that pans whichever  direction you move the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called 'reader mode'. It is something every application implements on its own. You will need to override the appropriate handlers (OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove, OnMouseUp).

The guidelines for scrolling and panning can be found at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545459.aspx

Also, see an earlier post on this web site: [C# - Pan cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397931/c-pan-cursor)